# Problem installing Oracle 19c to symlinked directory from RPM

Tags: oracle, redhat

I've created destination directory and linked it to default install path:

```
$mkdir /u01/oracle
$ln -s /u01/oracle /opt
```

Then I've changed the owner:

```
$sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall /opt/oracle
```

But when I tried to install RPM I got an error:

```
$sudo rpm -i ./oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: ./oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY

[SEVERE] The install cannot proceed because ORACLE_BASE directory (/opt/oracle)
is not owned by "oracle" user. You must change the ownership of ORACLE_BASE
directory to "oracle" user and retry the installation.

error: %prein(oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error: oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64: install failed
```

How to properly fix this problem?

Comment: So you have a directory `/u01/oracle/oracle` owned by `oracle:oinstall`?

Comment: Who owns `/u01` and `/u01/oracle`?

Comment: I would suggest that the proper fix is to eliminate the use of the symlink.  Why do you feel you should do it that way?

Comment: Owner of `/u01/oracle` is also `oracle:oinstall`

Comment: @EdStevens, I'm using symlink because I cant relocate /opt to another disk and current disk has no space for installing Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

you cant do that unless oracle user has a permission on the original directory here is an example explain to you what is exactly happening (in the example I am going to create normal text file)

```
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna ~]$ sudo mkdir /test
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna ~]$ sudo ln -s /test/ ./test
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna ~]$ cd ./test/
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$ touch 1
touch: cannot touch '1': Permission denied
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$ ls -alrt
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root root 4096 Oct 21 18:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Oct 21 18:15 .
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$ 
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$ sudo chmod 0777 /test
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$ touch 1.txt
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$ ls -altr
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root      root      4096 Oct 21 18:15 ..u 
-rw-rw-r--.  1 aabuhasna aabuhasna    0 Oct 21 18:18 1.txt
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root      root      4096 Oct 21 18:18 .
[aabuhasna@aabuhasna test]$
```

but in your case you need to use `sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01/oracle` this is a prerequisite from Oracle, there is no workaround for that

Note: softlink will not provide full access and\or ownership on the original directory

Comment: Ahmad, your command `sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall mkdir /u01/oracle` didn't work with error `chown: cannot access 'mkdir': No such file or directory`. I guess you were suggesting creating original folder with proper permissions so I tried this: `$ sudo su - oracle $ cd /u01 $ mkdir oracle $ ls -l total 20 drwx------ 2 root   root     16384 Oct 19 23:34 lost+found drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall  4096 Oct 28 12:26 oracle $ exit $ cd ~/distr $ sudo rpm -i ./oracle-database-ee-19c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` And result is same - ORACLE_BASE directory (/opt/oracle) is not owned by "oracle" user

Comment: @ant0nk my bad there is a typo in the command it should be `sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01/oracle` thanks for the correction I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, I cheked one more time, executed `sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01/oracle` then `ln -s /u01/oracle /opt`, but install attempt gives same error.